# Dual boot ubuntu 12.04 and Mageia

Tags: boot, nvidia, grub2, dual-boot

I am new to Linux, and I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04. I would like to set up a dual-boot of Mageia 2 and Ubuntu. Should I install Mageia first so when I install Ubuntu I can use GRUB2? Will it automatically set up boot options for Mageia?

Also, is there currently a fix for the Nvidia driver? I am using the Nvidia 6150SE card (nForce 430 chipset), and the current driver does not work.

Comment: Yes, it is is better to install Mageia first.  Ubuntu GRUB picks up all existing operating systems on your computer.

Comment: thanks, I will come back in a week or so to let everyone know how it worked out.

Comment: You probably would want to read this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/779213  but maybe the bug is fixed for 12.04.

Comment: And read this:  http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2010/10/12/ubuntu-10-10-manual-disk-partitioning-guide/  It might help too

Answer (score 0):

I'm using same graphical hardware as you I guess.

My experience is that "nvidia-current" doesn't work.
But "nvidia-current-updates" works.

Hope this helps.